# Join when table contains same values

Tags: sql, join

So I have a basic question regarding SQL joins. I have two tables as follows:

first table have 3 times 1 i.e. 3 rows having value as 1 in each row and second table have two rows having value as 1 in both rows

```
A                            
1                                                  
1                                                               
1                                                                              

B                                                                        
1                                                                                       
1
```

(A is 1st table and B is another table)

What will be the inner, left, right and full out join for these two tables?

Comment: The best way for you to learn would be to try doing these joins yourself.

Comment: Read up on SQL Joins. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: If **all** values are 1 - all your join will be the same and this is quite useless as an example..... use something more meaningful - table a with 3 or 4 *different* dates, and table B with some of those dates and e.g. a second column representing the sales achieved that day - or something else - all 1 is not very helpful to illustrate the types of joins...

Comment: And you can test it double on www.dbfiddle.com!

Comment: @marc_s yes all joins will be same but I just want to know whether the result will have 6 rows or just 3 rows?

Comment: All of them will have six rows - each of the three rows in table A will be combine with both rows from table B - rendering six rows in the result. Or each of the two rows in table B will be joined to each of the three rows in table A (for a right join) - again resulting in 6 rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks! that will be very useful.